MongoDB querying optimization (pymongo)
I have a database that contains around 75k JSON files. Each JSON file has a structure like
{
    'testResults': {
                            test1: 1, #1 or 0 depending if the test passed or failed, respectively
                            test2: 0,
                            ...,
                            test52: 1,
                   },
}

I am using pymongo and have written a query to give me the total number of files that passed each test and the pass rate like below:
list(mycol.aggregate([
            {
                "$project":{'testResults':{"$objectToArray":"$individual_test_outcomes"}}
            },
            {
                "$unwind":"$testResults"
            },    
            {
                "$group": {
                '_id': "$testResults.k",
                'pass': {"$sum":"$testResults.v"},
                'count': {"$sum":1},},
            },
            {
                "$sort":{'_id':1},
            },
            {
              "$addFields":{
                    'passRate': {"$divide":["$pass","$count"]},
            },  
        }
    ]))

however, this query is quite slow and for 75k files it takes about 3.5 seconds. I was wondering if there was any way to improve my query to optimize its performance time. I can restructure the JSON files if needed to optimize the query if needed

The fields like test1n test2 does not look very smart. Try to use more generic fields. Consider to use arrays.
